How to stop auto-increment from assigning an ID in SQL when inserting a new record via API?
I'm currently building an API to add new items to my database, and I have a function to insert a new item. However, every time I add a new item, the database ignores the ID I provide and generates a unique ID automatically.
My professor mentioned that this happens because each column in the database is set to auto-increment, which causes the database to automatically assign a new ID during the insert.
Is there a way to disable the auto-increment behavior for specific inserts so that I can use the ID I provide?
The API is below:
`.   [HttpPost(template:"AddTeacher")]
public IActionResult AddTeacher([FromBody]Teacher TeacherData)
{
using (MySqlConnection Connection = _context.AccessDatabase())
{
Connection.Open();

MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();

Command.CommandText = "insert into teachers (teacherfname, teacherlname, ) values (@teacherfname, @teacherlname)";
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherfname", TeacherData.TeacherFName);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherlname", TeacherData.TeacherLName);

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int insertedId = Convert.ToInt32(Command.LastInsertedId);
return Ok(insertedId);
}.   `

I tried explicitly setting the ID value when inserting a new record into the database. I expected the database to use the ID I provided, but instead, it ignored my ID and generated a new one automatically, likely due to the column being set to auto-increment.

'I tried explicitly setting the ID value when inserting a new record into the database' => Did you try in the same API, cant see that part in AddWithValue. Also read this
https://bobcares.com/blog/override-auto-increment-mysql/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20override%20the,the%20auto%2Dincrement%20column%20id.

This isn't really a C# or SQL question. It's a MySQL database configuration question. Open the database in a management tool and configure the PK column to not auto-increment. I don't really use MySQL but SQL Server has an identity attribute that is off for most columns and on for auto-incrementing PKs. Last time I looked, MySQL only used sequences to auto-generate PKs but that may have changed. This assumes that you never want IDs to be auto-generated, which you haven't really made clear either way.
